# How to resolve Forbidden issue in liferay?

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6

In liferay, when logged in user does not work continuously 30 minutes, he gets a sentence on top of it saying that `Don't refresh the page till you save it`. But if user refresh the page, he gets sign in page and if he enter the password there itself, he gets the Forbidden page with a sentence, `you don't have a permission to access the page`.

How to resolve this issue in liferay ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of these configuration values (here with their default values) in `portal-ext.properties` help you solve what you want:

```
#
# Specify the maximum number of sessions allowed. A value of 0 or less than
# 0 will mean that there is no limit. A value greater than 0 will limit the
# number of sessions by invalidating newer sessions.
#
# This property is not used unless the session max allowed filter is
# enabled.
#
session.max.allowed=0

#
# Specify the number of minutes before a session expires. This value is
# always overridden by the value set in web.xml.
#
session.timeout=30

#
# Specify the number of minutes before a warning is sent to the user
# informing the user of the session expiration. Specify 0 to disable any
# warnings.
#
session.timeout.warning=1

#
# Set the auto-extend mode to true to avoid having to ask the user whether
# to extend the session or not. Instead it will be automatically extended.
# The purpose of this mode is to keep the session open as long as the user
# browser is open and with a portal page loaded. It is recommended to use
# this setting along with a smaller "session.timeout", such as 5 minutes for
# better performance.
#
session.timeout.auto.extend=false

#
# Set this to true if the user is redirected to the default page when the
# session expires.
#
session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=false
```

plenty of options that are easy to configure, but I don't know what result exactly you'd be happy with.

Comment: What does it mean - This property is not used unless the session max allowed filter is enabled for(session.max.allowed=0)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the same user is trying to login after the session times out?

Comment: It might be the same user or other user .

Comment: The same user should not get permission error. There are high chances that some other user - who has lower permissions gets this error. Can you provide steps to reproduce this issue?